Use mutinity to decode base64 in quarkus
i'm studing Mutiny framework for quarkus 3 and i want to know if these code is correct or someone could be better than me. I want to read a big base64 string and decode them in a String to be saved in a file ( maybe a file in the future). I want to read 4 bytes at a time (because encoded is Base64 ) but in best multithreading fashion.
Is it appropriate code or wrong? How to? Thanks!
  @Inject
    ManagedExecutor managedExecutor;

 List<byte[]> resultDecoded = readBase64InStreamingFashionAndWriteTo(resultEncoded).collect().asList().await().indefinitely();
        //trasformao byte
        String resultMerge = resultDecoded.stream().map(b -> new String(b, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)).reduce("", (resultString, partialStr) -> resultString + partialStr);
        logger.info("Result Decoded: " + resultMerge);

public Multi<byte[]> readBase64InStreamingFashionAndWriteTo(String base64Str) throws IOException {
        logger.info("start thread read " + Thread.currentThread());
        AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger(1);
        return Uni.createFrom().item(base64Str)
               .emitOn(managedExecutor) //work pool
                .log()
               .onItem().transform(String::getBytes)
               .onItem().transform(ByteArrayInputStream::new)
               .onItem().transformToMulti(this::readChunkAsync)// processo asincrono
                .emitOn(managedExecutor)
                .onItem().transform( str -> {
                   if (i.getAndAdd(1) <= 2) logger.info(Thread.currentThread() + "**read partial string**: " + str);
                   return  str;})
               .onItem().transform(DatatypeConverter::parseBase64Binary);


    }

    private Multi<String> readChunkAsync(ByteArrayInputStream in) {
        return Multi.createFrom().emitter( em -> {  //emetto multi di stringhe (stream di stringhe generate leggendo 4 byte alla volta dal base64 in input)
                  try {
                      AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger(1);
                      byte[] buf = new byte[4];//4 bytes
                      int nread = -1;
                      while ((nread = in.read(buf, 0, buf.length)) != -1) {
                          if (i.getAndAdd(1) <= 2)  logger.info(Thread.currentThread() + "**emiting**: ");
                          em.emit(new String(buf, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                      }
                  }catch(Exception ex){
                      //
                  } finally {
                      em.complete();
                  }
                }
        );
    }


This will work, but since there are no async I/O in any of the operations (see onItem().transform(...) then the same code in an imperative loop would be more efficient than those operators chaining.

Do you mean that I have to use for example the Java nio2, instead ByteArrayinputStream?  Do you have or find an example for me?  Thanks

i can also use Vertx?

that's a very good point. introducing async pararelism on short simple procedural code blocks can add a bit of overhead. it usually doesn't pay for itself if there's no I/O operations when the async would benefit from by processing something else instead of actively wait.

But for some rare cases, such async procedural code are good for fast-release of temporary states such as objects and data structures created inside methods that end up existing for a longer time then they should. In that case, reactive programming helps you to split the memory needs in smaller parts. But I think this is a thing only when you have extremely high concurrency, since in normal scenarios the memory is very well managed by the platform itself.
